# view .pdf file from subfolder

Tags: errors, texmaker

How can I view .pdf file from subfolder? Command

```
"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" ./subfolder/%.pdf
```

doesn't work and I get:

> "Error: could not start the command"

On the other hand, command

```
"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf
```

works correctly (of course, if the .pdf file exists in parent directory). I use Texmaker. Thank you.

Comment: I don't use Windows or Texmaker but my guess is to leave out the leading ./ in the path

Comment: I use TeXstudio under Debian, but this solution should work on TeXmaker under Windows.

I set

    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape -jobname="./subfolder/%" %.tex

for `pdflatex` compilation, and

    okular ./subfolder/%.pdf

for displaying the pdf within `okular`.

Comment: This is my whole command: pdflatex -aux-directory=others -output-directory=pdfs %.tex|"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" ./pdfs/%.pdf. Folders "others" and "pdfs" are created successfully, but command for view .pdf file from "pdfs" still not working.

Comment: Just to be sure: Your subfolder contains no spaces? (Else you need `"` around the pdf-path.

Comment: I added " around pdf-path, but still same error. As you can see above, my subfolder name is "pdfs" without any spaces.

Comment: Even if I type whole path of .pdf file (that is "C:/Users/.../pdfs/%.pdf") command is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Texstudio and command

> `pdflatex -aux-directory=others -output-directory=pdfs %.tex|txs:///view-pdf "C:/Users/.../pdfs/?rm.pdf"`

finallly works but doesn't in Texmaker. So problem was with Texmaker. Maybe Texstudio is more sophisticated than Texmaker.